# Prevent a lot of brute force attacks on Exim2

Tags: linux, networking

Some people or computers have been trying to log in a lot of times on my Linux DirectAdmin server over the last few days. 
I am receiving a lot of messages of brute force attacks for Exim2 in DirectAdmin.

I have already installed Fail2Ban and `Block_IP.SH` is on the server, so if the user fails 15 times to log in then the IP address is blocked.

How can I prevent the brute force attacks from continuing?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oLmGOES.png]

Comment: You did more or less what can be done. I'd probably lower the number of attempts that suffice to get blocked, especially *during* an attack. Personally I use `ipset` and netfilter rules to keep bad guys out. If you are on my black list, you better not try again for a looong time, otherwise your listing gets an updated expiration value.

Comment: How can i use 'ipset' and netfilter with directadmin?

Comment: I don't have a clue. I don't use such canned administration interfaces for the most part, because I want the full control. The terminal gives me just that ;) ... IIRC Fail2Ban and similar solutions are picking up slowly on IP Sets. So if you have a recent version and configure it accordingly, you may get a similar effect as my semi-automated but custom solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is answered on https://serverfault.com/questions/692979/block-brute-force-attacks-on-exim2/692991#692991.

Part of the issue seems to be allowing authentication on an plain text connection.

Fail2ban should catch after 3 tries, but may need additional regexes.